# how to configure blender 2.75 in the dynamic topology settings to reach the desired effect

Tags: sculpting, dynamic-topology

Hello to everyone blender gurus,

I'm trying to follow the piero tutorial and immediately I've freezed cause a problem. Since it is using blender 2.66 and I'm using blender 2.75,there are a lot of differences inside the dynamic topology area. I would like to reach the effect that you can usee on the video that I've attached. I've tried to configure blender 2.75 in some way to reach it,but It didn't work. Can you explain to me how to do ?

this is the video that I'm following :

[blender 2.66 video tutorial](http://psychonews.it/dati/2015-12-13_17-48-31.mp4)

and here you can see how I have configured blender 2.75

[my blender 2.75 configuration settings and how it works for me](http://psychonews.it/dati/2015-12-13_17-50-22.png)

very thanks.

Comment: I think that if you watch the video and the picture that I've attached,you will understand very well.

Comment: also because I don't know how to explain carefully my problem using the words.